# Approach to classify blocks of time series

Tags: deep-learning, classification, time-series

I am wondering if there exists an approach to classify blocks of time series, and not specifically individual time series. If so, can you point me out papers/articles/tutorials where these type of data are classified ?

**For example :** 
We would extract time series for each country that depict these information : Human Development Index evolution, urbanization, financial situation, investments, etc. If we group all these time series we would make a block of economical information for each country.
The countries are already pre-classified to developed, underdeveloped, or semi-developed countries.

Comment: DId you find a technique to classify blocks of a time series?

Comment: @LazarusThurston Unfortunately no. However, this R package may be interesting https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ClustBlock/html/ClustBlock-package.html

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to ignore the time component, then the problem can be framed as [multi-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification). You can use any multi-class classification algorithm (e.g., naive Bayes, logistics regression, or a neural network).

Your particular problem would be predicting one of the three country states based on the features for that country.